# GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext & Clients.Others

Tags: signalr

I seem to be having a problem calling:

```
Clients.Others.SomeJavascriptFunction;
```

When I use

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("MyHub");
```

I seem to be only able to get this to work within a Hub.
Can anybody shed some light on this.

Regards

Mike

**Update**

After David's comment

I found that I could do the following:

```
public class MyHub1 : Hub
{        
    public static HubConnectionContext MyProperty { get; set; }        

    public void Start()
    {
        MyProperty = Clients;
    }        
}
```

Then call Start in my js

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    sig.server.start();
});
```

Which then allows me to call my function from my api controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
        var changes = _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);

        var stuff = MyHub1.MyProperty;

        stuff.Others.refreshToDos();

        return changes;
    }
```

Maybe a complete hack but seems to work.

Can anyone see any problems with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others only makes sense when you have a connection id to exclude. Others is shorthand for Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId). When you're outside the hub there's no current connection id so you can't use Others.

You need to pass the connection id from the client to the API to want to use to do AllExcept.

Comment: Thanks David, I have updated my question. Do you see problems with what I am doing?

Comment: Yes, everything is wrong with it. You're capturing an instance property statically so the hub instance will never die. Never *ever* do anything like this. Instead do what I said and pass the connection id from the client to your method and use the GlobalHost to get ahold of the hub context.